# After upgrade to magento 2.2.7 The element 'gallery' already has a child with alias 'content' give error on exception.log file

Tags: magento2, admin, magento2.2.7

After upgrade to magento 2.2.7 then give following error in exception.log file

`main.CRITICAL: The element 'gallery' already has a child with alias 'content' {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\LocalizedException(code: 0): The element 'gallery' already has a child with alias 'content' at /vendor/magento/framework/Data/Structure.php:609)"} []`